# Как подключить встроенный класс в Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Я наверное очень туплю...
Мне нужно подключить класс Form и Fleunt. Как это сделать ? Что надо написать полсле use?

Comment: О какой версии Laravel речь? Какие варианты подключения вы уже попробовали?

Comment: 5 версия. Пока только подключил класс Fluent с помощью строчки use DB;

Answer (score 1):

В шаблонах ничего дополнительно писать не нужно, можно просто использовать класс, поскольку этот фасад и шаблоны находятся в одном пространстве имён - в глобальном. Это же касается и прочего вашего кода, который не включён в какое-либо пространство имён.

В остальных случаях достаточно просто указать `use Form;`.

Только убедитесь, что у вас установлен [соответствующий пакет](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html).